# childByAppendingPath Causes Segues Due To Being Embedded In Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, firebase

For some reason when I do...

```
usersRef.childByAppendingPath("users").setValue(newUser)
```

It causes up to 7 random segues. These segues are segues from a few view controllers back. All of these view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller. I'm not sure at all why this is happening but I know childByAppendingPath is causing it because when childByAppendingPath is removed the segues don't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Firebase auth in the original VC which you have set as a segue that triggers without auth from Firebase? If this is so, then maybe you have the Firebase auth session set to a short period only and when it runs out you are sent back to the Original VC.